# $datetime->diff returns zero despite it being clearly 1 day apart?

Tags: php, date

so i basically have two dates. today which is 2016-09-15 and the mysql one which is 2016-09-16. i made a function known as timeAgo($id) which fetches the id from mysql and returns it as datetime. here is the function:

```
     public function timeAgo($id)
 {
    $sql = "SELECT post_date from arts where id=:id";
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id',$id);
    $stmt->execute();
    /* i think this is the problem? */ $date = new DateTime(date('y-m-d'));
    $rowdate = $stmt->fetchColumn();
    $rowdate = new DateTime();
     $total = $rowdate->diff($date)->format('%a days');
    return $total;

 }
```

it should basically return 1 day but it actually returns 0 days..?
i know my html isnt important but here it is anyways.

```
 <span class="postdate"><i class="fa fa-calendar-times-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Posted: <?=$artmanager->timeAgo($id);?></span>
```

here is screenshot : 
[image]

Comment: You are comparing today to today. You never use the date from your database.

Comment: what? how am i doing that? also 1 downvote? lol

Comment: `$rowdate = new DateTime();` uses today's date.

Comment: ooooooh so u se new datetime($rowdate)

Answer (score 3):

As I mention in the comments, you are comparing today to today because you never actually use the date from your database. You overwrite that variable with a DateTime object representing today.

```
$date = new DateTime();
$rowdate = $stmt->fetchColumn();
$rowdate = new DateTime($rowdate);
$total = $rowdate->diff($date)->format('%a days');
return $total;
```

Comment: yeah i got it i had to use new datetime($rowrate). pretty unfriendly to downvote (idk if its u) but i'm still at fault i should of twice checked very dumb of me